# CSS3 selectors - select very first item or item after

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say a have the following code:

```
<nav id="main-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 Level 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 Level 1</a></li>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Link 1 Level 2</a>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And now I want to to set first `ul`'s height to 100px and second `ul` should be 300px.

When I try

```
nav ul {
     height: 100px
}
```

Second `ul` also inherits this value.

I was trying "~", "+", ">", first-childs etc. but don't know how to do that, even with documentation.

Is there a good explained (preferably with demos/screens) guide to new css3 selectors? W3 Table is too nerdy for me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: ">" and "+" are actually CSS 2.1 selectors. 456 Berea Street has good explanations. http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200509/css_21_selectors_part_1/ and http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/

Answer (score 2):

Just select any `ul` that is a descendant of `ul` and give it that style, if you will only have 2 layers of `<ul>`s. No need for any special CSS2/CSS3 combinators since `<ul>` cannot directly contain `<ul>`, plus you don't have to worry about IE either.

```
nav ul {
     height: 100px;
}

nav ul ul {
     height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To select direct children of an element, and not any descendant, you should use the `>` syntax. In your case (after you put the second `ul` inside a `li`) you need:

```
nav > ul {
     height: 100px;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
     height: 300px;
}
```

<del>*Extra: It doesn't really make sense to have a 300px item inside a 100px item. Why do you want that?*</del>

*Another extra: Try to read the w3c docs, it will save you some time in the long run. What you don't understand you can always ask on SO.*

Comment: nav > ul > ul will not work, because the markup will be nav > ul > li > ul. But nav > ul ul would work.

Comment: 100px/300px was just an example. Ok, i'll try to stick to w3 docs. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, how imporant is browser compatibility to you? All of those selectors you mentioned have issues in various versions of IE (IE8 is obviously better than IE7, but even IE8 is missing a lot of CSS selectors)

Simple nested selectors (ie just a space between the CSS names) will work for you - although as you say, setting `nav li {height:100px;}` sets it for all the LIs, you can override that with `nav li li {height:300px;}` to set the inner one back the way you want it.

If you want to use the 'correct' selectors, the one you want is `>`.

```
nav>ul>li {
    height:100px;
}
```

This will only affect the outer LI elements, not the inner one. However as I say, it won't work in older versions of IE (fortunately it does work in IE7 and up, so it's only an issue if you want to support IE6).

You say that you've found the various selectors quite hard to grasp. I recommend you visit [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html). For a start, it's got a very handy compatibility chart showing which browsers support which selectors, but it's also got excellent examples of how each selector works, which should help you understand them a bit better.